# C++ why is this returned?

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism

I have written a class 'clsFileThread', this class is derived from 'clsThread'. 'clsThread' is derived from 'QThread'

In another class I have written an access method which returns a pointer to 'QObject'.  In this method have something like:

```
QObject* clsScriptHelper::use(QJsonValue strModule) {
    QObject* pobjModule = nullptr;

    if (strModule.toString().compare("fileIO") == 0) {
        pobjModule = new clsFileThread();
    }
    return pobjModule;
}
```

When the pointer is returned it is a pointer to 'clsThread', why?  I would have thought that the pointer would be of type QObject, then using polymorphism I could access members and methods higher up, but this isn't the case.

What I want to be able to do is access the methods of 'clsFileThread' through the pointer returned by 'use' but this doesn't work.

Comment: That's the way inheritance works.   Through a pointer to a base class it is possible to access only members known to the base class.  Calls of virtual functions (which can directly access derived members, since they are members of the derived class) resolve to their most derived variants, unless you specifically force the call of a base's version of the function.    Any members that the derived classes have which are not known to the base class are inaccessible, unless you specifically cast the base pointer to a pointer the appropriate derived class.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the returned pointer is a pointer to `clsThread`? (What is telling you that? What exactly is that something telling you?)

Comment: @Peter, My understanding of polymorphic behaviour is that a class can be access as its derived class type by returning a pointer to a base class type.

Comment: @JaMit, because that exactly what's reported when I look at the type reported by the returned pointer.

Comment: @SPlatten *How* are you looking at the type "reported" by the returned pointer? A [pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) does not have an intrinsic way to report anything. (It has no methods.) The type of the pointer returned by that function is what is declared: "pointer-to-`QObject`". Again: What is telling you that the returned pointer is a pointer to `clsThread`? (I'm pretty sure your program does not write to `std::out` something like _"I got a pointer to clsThread"_. So what is telling you this?)

Comment: @JaMiT , using the debugger.

Comment: @SPlatten Thank you, that is progress. Not enough, but progress. Which debugger? And (again) what exactly is your debugger telling you (copy-and-paste the text if possible, although this might be one case where a screenshot is useful)?

Comment: Oh, and your question would be clearer if you included the code that tried to "access members and methods higher up" along with an explanation of how that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer returned is type `QObject*`, even though the object itself is `clsFileThread*` (because that's how you defined the `use` method).  Therefore, accessing the return value directly won't allow access to clsFileThread methods.

The class inheritence looks like this:

```
clsFileThread > clsThread > QThread > QObject
```

If you want to access the return object as if it's a clsFileThread, you can `dynamic_cast` the return value, for example:

```
QObject* obj = clsScriptHelper::use(whatever);
clsFileThread* clsFileThreadObject = dynamic_cast<clsFileThread*>(obj);
if (clsFileThreadObject)
{
   clsFileThreadObject->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: This assumes the cast is valid.   `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` if `obj` does not actually point to a `clsFileThread`.

Comment: @Peter, I would agree with you on QObject*, however as mentioned in my post that's not what I'm seeing, the returned type is an instance of clsThread*

Comment: @Peter, the isn't the way polymorphism is supposed to work, it should be perfectly possible to return a pointer of the base class type then access the object via its base class and access methods in derived classes without having to re-cast the pointer.

Comment: @SPlatten Only if the methods were declared `virtual` in the base class.  A base class won't magically know about methods that only exist in its various subclasses.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you, I will add those, that makes perfect sense, what doesn't make sense is when I look at this in the debugger 'this' isn't showing up as an instance of clsFileThread but as an instance of clsThread.

Comment: @jdigital, the only thing with your answer is that the "use" function is supposed to identify the module and return the correct pointer...doing it outside of the "use" function kind of defeats the point of the "use" function....any other way of doing this?

Comment: instead of returning a QObject, return a base class that has virtual declarations for all the methods you need (but you already know this, since it was mentioned above). another option is to create wrapper methods for each specific method you want to call, and get rid of the `use()` method -- or something along those lines.

Comment: @jdigital, I decided this morning that I'm going to revisit the design and change it so that the "use" method actually loads a "module" as a separate process, the main helper script thread which has the "use" method will then use IPC to communicate with the "module" using a handle returned by the "use" method.  This will mean that all communicate to the module will go via the central process and communication from the module will also go via the central process.

Comment: @jdigital, your answer isn't the solution I used but thank you for your help and assistance, I will tick it off as I now have a solution.

Comment: glad you found a solution.  your approach reminds me of a product i worked on that uses strings to handle polymorphism.  any target object can receive any string and then parse the string to determine what action to take (in this case, strings were passed directly rather than via IPC).